# I want to know how to implement supermodel in titanium appcelerator?

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I want to know how to implement supermodel in titanium appcelerator? i want step by step implementation of this supermodel http://www.clearlyinnovative.com/simple-integration-supermodel-appcelerator-titanium-alloy

Comment: The format for the site requires you to give it a try first. If you do that and have a problem, then post an example of the problem and ask for specific help.

Comment: @Brick i have added the supermodel.js in lib folder but i am not getting how to implement  all the given steps  for every snippet at left bottom they have given a name to that file as 1.js,2.js,3.js etc so my doubt is should i create models? where that code will go in an app?

Comment: 1.js,2.js ... it`s   steps names  and you will use the only final model file  ! if you want final model see https://gist.github.com/aaronksaunders/069433c5823444f5973e#file-complete_source-js